# How to add new row in jsp with incremented value from server

Tags: jquery, jsp, struts2

This is my code to add another row in div. On click on `#add` it will fetch new row and append to  `.panel-body` this code is working properly but I am not able to set incremented values in newly added row.

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $(document).on('click', '#add', function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                        url: "getNewRow",
                        data: 1,
                        dataType: "html",
                        success: function(data) {
                        $(".panel-body").append(data);
                        }
                });
        });
```

In struts.xml

```
<action name="getNewRow" class="iland.expense.ExpenxeAction" method="getNewRow">
            <result name="success">/pages/expense/NewRow.jsp</result>
            <result name="input">/pages/expense/NewRow.jsp</result>
            <result name="login">/pages/login.jsp</result>            
            <result name="UNAUTHORIZED">/pages/Unautho.jsp</result>
        </action>
```

In NewRow.jsp

```
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<div class="row" id="<s:property value="id"/>">
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-1 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
        <label>Expensed Type</label>
        <s:select name="expenseList[0].param" 
                  list="'advertisement','food'"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-1 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
        <label>Amount</label>
        <s:textfield name="expenseList[0].value" value="%{expenseList[0].value}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-1 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
        <label>Date</label>
        <s:textfield name="expenseList[0].dt" value="%{expenseList[0].dt}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1 cl">
        <label ></label>
        <img src="images/delete.png"/>
    </div>

</div>
```

Here `<s:property value="id"/>` is incremented value which i want to assing in NewRow.jsp in  and  and want to set  `expenseList[0]` to `expenseList[1]`

How to do this.

Comment: How this value is incremented, show the code.

Comment: data: 1, is current value. In action I am increment it by one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem.
In action I am incrementing value by one and made change in NewRow.jsp as below

```
<%@taglib uri="/struts-tags" prefix="s"%>
<div class="row" id="<s:property value="rowId"/>">
    <div class="col-xs-1"></div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-1 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
        <label>Expensed Type</label>
        <s:select name="expenseList[%{rowId}].param" 
                  list="'advertisement','food'"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-1 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
        <label>Amount</label>
        <s:textfield name="expenseList[%{rowId}].value" value="%{expenseList[%{rowId}].value}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-1 col-sm-6 col-lg-3">
        <label>Date</label>
        <s:textfield name="expenseList[%{rowId}].dt" value="%{expenseList[%{rowId}].dt}"/>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group col-xs-1 col-sm-1 col-lg-1 cl">
        <label ></label>
        <img src="images/delete.png"/>
    </div>
```

`%{rowId}` solved my problem.